# ArgumentError in CoursesController#create argument out of range

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My courses_controller

```
def create
     @course = Course.new(postparam)
     if @course.save
        flash[:notice] = t('course_created')
        redirect_to courses_path
     else
       render 'new'
     end
end

def postparam
     params.require(:course).permit(:course_name, :section_name, :code, :grading_type, batches_attributes: [:name, :start_date, :end_date])
end
```

I am getting an error as :

> ArgumentError in CoursesController#create argument out of range

Comment: the `postparam` is declared as `private`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)
Please look at [ask] and format your code in the question (`edit`). This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not properly converting `start_date`, and `end_date` in your controller. You first need to process `start_date`, and `end_date`, and make a `Date` object that you could actually pass into `save` method through `params`.

Right now, your `start_date` would be consisting of three parts:

1. start_date(1i) # it contains the year
2. start_date(2i) # it contains the month
3. start_date(3i) # it contains the day

You can actually do something like following to get a date object:

```
Date.civil(start_date(1i), start_date(2i), start_date(3i))
```

For more information, you can search the relevant topics in Rails official guides.

Comment: Thanks for your help.